# How to notify the client about the Rest Endpoint changes

Tags: java, rest, web-services

This question was asked to me recently in an interview:

You have one rest end point which is exposed to the client, Client uses this rest endpoint.Now, You have changed the rest endpoint, So if client hits the old rest end point url, How to notify the client that the rest end point has been changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can  inform client about  Redirects that indicate the resource might be available at a different URI, as provided by the Location field, as in the status codes 301 (Moved Permanently), 302 (Found), and 307 (Temporary Redirect).

like

**301 Moved Permanently:**

```
URI uri = ...
return Response.status(Status.MOVED_PERMANENTLY).location(uri).build();
```

**307 Temporary Redirect:**

```
URI uri = ...
return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
```